# How to extract unique rows based on a criteria across different sheets on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, flatten, google-query-language

I have a main sheet with a lot of data but here it is simplified:

| Manager | Employee | Project | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | James | Pineapple | 1/1/2021 |
| John | James | Banana | 1/1/2021 |
| Alex | Robert | Apple | 1/1/2021 |
| Sally | Mindy | Kiwi | 2/1/2021 |
| Sally | Mindy | Orange | 1/1/2021 |
| Sally | Matthew | Tomato | 2/30/2021 |
| Sally | Mindy | Grape | 1/1/2021 |
| John | Vlad | Orange | 2/30/2021 |

I tried using a formula that looks like this:

=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX($B$2:$B,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A=B$1,ROW($A$2:$A)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$A))+1,""),ROW(B2))))

However it's not working.

I got the =UNIQUE() for each person from column A:

| UNIQUE |
| --- |
| John |
| Alex |
| Sally |

I transpose this into their own columns:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Alex | Sally |

and then I want a formula under each name that will go through the range that I specify

| John |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| =UNIQUE() for column B "Employee" based on the criteria "John" in column A | =COUNTIF() |  |
| James | 2 |  |
| Vlad | 1 |  |

And this would be useful to figure out the projects based on the criteria of column A "Manager"

| John |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| =UNIQUE() Column C "Project" | =COUNTIF() |  |
| Pineapple | 1 |  |
| Banana | 1 |  |
| Orange | 1 |  |

What's the best way of organizing this?

Comment: what is the final output you seek?

Comment: I want a way to split up all UNIQUE manager names (John, Alex, Sally) into their own sheets. I have a script to do this. In those sheets I will have do a "sheetname" formula that utilizes another piece of script that references the sheet's name. Then I could effectively create a formula for each sheet that relies on the main spreadsheet for data and analyze all the data in columns B-D for each manager. John's spreadsheet will show all the employees under them that were laid out in the spreadsheet, their count, the projects and count, the dates and count, etc. I need the "criteria" formula

Comment: can you share a copy/sample of your sheet with an example of the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({A2:C}, "select Col3,count(Col2) where Col3 is not null group by Col3 pivot Col1")
```

[image]

Comment: I really like this approach, but instead of producing a count, how can I instead assign the "project"/fruit under each manager (Alex, John, Sally). Basically make it scan every project and attaching it to the appropriate person? Under Alex | John | Sally, it would list all the projects that was found attached to their row? Ideally I would then be able to create a separate table for each manager and also analyze the date field and create a date count, etc.

Comment: @usernametaken try: `=QUERY({A2:C}, "select max(Col3) where Col3 is not null group by Col3 pivot Col1")`

Comment: That's almost perfect! Is there a specific way to remove white space, since if I use 50 names and a list of 500 projects, there will be a ton of gaps? Is there a way to index every project for each manager in a clean listing/column per manager? And what's your advice regarding if I want to see if there are duplicate projects for one name, or if I could do a count, or add more analysis like connecting the "date" to the project + manager name to see how long it has been per project? For example, what if I wanted the 1/1/2021 date connected to the Pineapple project that is John's?

Comment: @usernametaken https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLyfP.png

Comment: @usernametaken https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUFIQ.png

Comment: Brilliant! Just an FYI I am doing query from a different sheet and referencing the main sheet, how would I reference it properly in the "select max(Col3) ..." portion, where Col3 and all other references are actually in a different sheet? Since query is no longer directly connected to those column references. Should I enter a reference and range in the beginning curly bracket or is there a better way like directly tying each column reference to the other sheet?

Comment: @usernametaken no, you do nothing with quoted part of the query. all you need to do is to reference ranges properly `sheetname!A2:B`, etc

Comment: Thank you it happened to work after a bit of tweaking! Is there a way to replace the Char(13) part or format that differently? The issue is the query result will break if I index a part of it in another sheet. I double click the cell and it line breaks after every space. The text being queried looks like "123456 Example Text" and when I copy it or try to reference it it's read as "123456ExampleText". Thank you!

Comment: @usernametaken use: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1jps.png